# Custom Gridview in fragmnet with Volley request

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley, android-gridview

I'm trying get some data from my server and populate it on my gridView which located in fragment, I'm using volley JsonArrayRequest, to fetch the data from the server. 
My problem is that, as the request executed, it stuck forever, the ProgressDialog
doesn't dismiss, and no response delivered.

The url string and onCreate:

```
 private static final String URL_INDEX = "http://myserveripadrss/product.php";

 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    images = new ArrayList<>();
    productTitles = new ArrayList<>();


    fetchServer();
}


private void fetchServer(){
    //Showing a progress dialog while our app fetches the data from url
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait...","Fetching data...",false,false);

    //Creating a json array request to get the json from our api
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest( URL_INDEX,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Dismissing the progressdialog on response
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //Displaying our grid
                    showGrid(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    );
```

the php returning valid json, but still like i said no reaction from the response listner

Any advice would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: This can b a server issue not from your coding side

Comment: i guess so, though volley StringRequest did worked, so after small json convert i got my array.